# Powershell script not able to log sql server2012 database "output window" message

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am running this powershell script to run sql scripts against my database SQLServer2012, all the scripts are running sucessfully.
Issue is in log files, logs related to "table created sucessfully" or "one row updated" are not being logged.Only output of select statement is logging there.

Please suggest

```
   push-location;
   Import-Module sqlps;
   Pop-Location;
   foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem -path "D:\Mywork\powersh\SQLDump\" -Filter *.sql | sort-object ) 
   { 
     try
     {

     $timestamp = get-date -uformat '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%p';
     $out = "D:\Mywork\powersh\SQLDump\OUTPUT\" + $f.name.split(".")[0]+ "_" +$timestamp+ ".txt" ;

    $mydata = invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $f.fullname -serverinstance MyServer\SQLEXPRESS -database AdventureWorks;
    $mydata | out-file -filePath $out;

    }
   catch {
   $out = "D:\Mywork\powersh\SQLDump\OUTPUT\ErrorLog"+ "_" +$timestamp+ ".txt" ;
   $error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName +"test" | out-file -filePath $out;
    }
  }
  remove-module sqlps;
```

Comment: Hmm... normal sqlcmd (or SSMS even) doesn't print anything when a table is created. Does your script have a print statement or something like that in it that would make it do that? As for the updates, that is strange. If it were me, I'd use sqlcmd with the -o parameter to specify the output file instead of invoke-sqlcmd.

Comment: I am in a process of scripting through powershell for creating database structure for multiple clients and need to know whether all the sql statements run sucessfully and if not then want to know what all query which which fails. right now no print statement is in my query.

Comment: Fair enough, but my comments above still stand. After executing your script (via invoke-sqlcmd with -AbortOnError or plain old sqlcmd with -b), check the $? variable; it contains $true if the last command succeeded, $false if it didn't.